# Moment js. Comparison two dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

How to compare two dates with moment js. I used `diff()` method , but not worked. How I solve it ?

```
  let lastMessageMinute = moment("06-30-2022").format("HH:mm");
  let currentTime = moment(new Date()).format("HH:mm");
  const differenceOfTimes = currentTime.diff(lastMessageMinute, "hours");
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert both dates (before formatting) to milliseconds and compare them. Like

```
if(lastMessageMinute.valueOf() === currentTime.valueOf())
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do like moment().diff()

Your syntax -> moment().format().diff() this is not accept by moment js.

For Example,

```
var a = moment("18.05.2022", "DD.MM.YYYY");
var b = moment(new Date(), "DD.MM.YYYY");
console.log("diff", b.diff(a, 'hours'));
```